# Color/fill one point differently in a scatterplot

Tags: r, col

I am using base R graphics to make a scatterplot with thousands of data points.  One point out of these has the highest 'y' value.  I want to fill this point to make it look different.  In the past I have accomplished this with one of the following.  Of course then the number of points were very few and thus I was able to manage it easily.  Now I have ~3000 points.  Any ideas?

```
col=c{'black','black','black','red','black','black'}
pch=c(16,16,16,17,16,16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Identify the max and make your color vector

```
set.seed(47)
n <- 1e4
xx <- runif(n)
yy <- rexp(n)
colors <- rep("black", n)
colors[which.max(yy)] <- "red"
plot(xx, yy, col = colors, pch = 16)
```

Option 2: Plot the max separately. This is probably easier, especially if you want to adjust more characteristics than just color.

```
plot(xx, yy, pch = 16)
points(xx[which.max(yy)], yy[which.max(yy)], col = "red", pch = 17, cex = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a bit faster to just do:

```
plot(xx, yy, col=(yy==max(yy)), pch=19)
```

This will create a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values which will be coerced into `1`s and `0`s, so you may have to attach a `+1` to that statement to avoid using white:

```
plot(xx, yy, col=(yy==max(yy))+1, pch=19)
```

Comment: Senor: I tried your answer first, and while it worked, all the points got filled solid and I didn't have control on the color.  I tried +1 through +3, but could not figure out a way to keep rest of the points as unfilled circles.  Thank you anyway for taking time to suggest a solution though.

Comment: Oh that's cause of `pch=19`. Just get rid of that argument and it'll be like normal